# Implementing Version Control For Users in Python Flask App

Tags: python, flask

I'm currently developing a Python Flask app that will allow users to write out paragraphs and store them in a MySQL database. Are there any Python libraries that will let users have the benefits of version control? Ideally users would be able to track edits so that users can revert to previous versions of the text they've written.

Comment: `bazaar`, `mercurial`, `git`? or do you mean something like `sqlalchemy` or `alembic`?

Comment: I'm looking for git functionality, but for end users that are saving their writing in my app. When they save their work, it would get stored in a MySQL database (I'm using SQL Alchemy as my ORM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using SQL Alchemy, checkout:  [sqlalchemy-continuum](https://sqlalchemy-continuum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

**Features:**

- Does not store updates which don’t change anything
- Supports alembic migrations
- Can revert objects data as well as all object relations at given transaction even if the object was deleted
- Transactions can be queried afterwards using SQLAlchemy query syntax
- Querying for changed records at given transaction
- Querying for versions of entity that modified given property
- Querying for transactions, at which entities of a given class changed
- History models give access to parent objects relations at any given point in time

---

Or check [versioning-objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/examples.html#versioning-objects) in SQLAlchemy documentation.

I also found this tutorial [Database Content Versioning Using SQLAlchemy](http://bioinfo.iric.ca/database-content-versioning-using-sqlalchemy/) by Googling: `sqlalchemy history table`, you may find other solutions.